# How to filter array of objects based on nested object using Underscore?

Tags: filter, nested, underscore.js, javascript-objects

I am currently trying to filter an array of objects based on a child object. The object is structured like this:

```
{
    name: 'foo',
    status: 'fail',
    rules: [
        {
            name: 'bar',
            result: 'fail'
        },
        // so on and so forth ~13 rules
    ]
}
```

I want to filter down my results to all of the objects that have `rule a` with `status: fail`, `rule b` with `status: pass`, etc.

So far, this is what I have:

This works for one and only one parameter:

```
var data = _.filter(this.resultsCollection.toJSON(), function(obj) {
    return _.some(obj.rules, {name:params.rules[0].name});
});
```

To me, this should work and is more what I need since `_.some` only takes one parameter, but doesn't (just changing it to `_.where`):

```
var data = _.filter(this.resultsCollection.toJSON(), function(obj) {
    return _.where(obj.rules, {name:params.rules[0].name});
});
```

Really what I would like would be something more like this:

```
var data = _.where(this.resultsCollection.toJSON(), {
    rules: params.rules // params.rules being the array with name and result
});
```

It works being filtered down this way:

```
var data = _.where(this.resultsCollection.toJSON(), {status:'fail'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using vanilla javascript filter.

```
var data = this.resultsCollection.toJSON().filter(function(obj) {
        for (var i = 0; i < params.rules.length; i++) {
            var rule = params.rules[i];
            for (var k = 0; k < obj.rules.length; k++) {
                if(obj.rules[k].name.toLowerCase() == rule.name.toLowerCase()) {
                    if(obj.rules[k].result.toLowerCase() !== rule.result.toLowerCase()) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(i === obj.rules.length - 1) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
```